# Spring 3.2.15 & Hibernate 4.2.21 createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I upgrade Hibernate from 3.6 to 4.2.21 in a Spring 3.2.15 based application.

This my configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { myClass.class })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class JavaConfigSpring {

    // ############ SESSION FACTORY ############ //
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new     LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}

    // ############ TRANSACTION MANAGER ############ //
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        txManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
```

}

and my hibernate configuration file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx:MyBase</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>

    <!--Pool C3PO-->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>         
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>

    <mapping resource="com/toto/persistence/hibernate/hbm/Profiles.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/toto/persistence/hibernate/hbm/Role.hbm.xml"/>        

</session-factory>
```

And also I put @Transactional in the right places, this is where the error happens

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class LabelsFactory {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Labels> getLabels() {

    Criteria crit =     sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Labels.class);

        return crit.list();
    }
}
```

But when I start the application I got this error :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active     transaction

So apparently the transaction manager is not working

I tried to remove :

> `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>`

But then I got this new error :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

What is wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Try to find the code creating the criteria by looking at the trace from `createCriteria is not valid without active transaction`

Comment: @ben75 I added the class where the error happens in my original question. If I put this line in comment, the next "createCriteria" get a org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria

Comment: Remove `hibernate.current_session_context_class` as that breaks integration. The fact that you receive the error indicates you have an error in your setup.